# How do I apply a jQuery accordion to div loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to turn a div i with jQuery's load function into a jQuery accordion.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I first load nav.html to #nav then I attempt to make #nav into a jQuery accordion. #nav loads correctly but I can't seem to make it into a accordion.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nav").load("nav.html"); 
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#accordionNav").accordion({
                heightStyle: "content",
                collapsible: true,
                active: 1
            });
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

nav.html:

```
<nav>
    <div id="accordionNav">
    <h3>Surveys</h3>
        <div class="accordionDropDown">
            <ul id="surveys">
                <li><a href='Nutritional_Supplement.html'>Nutritional Supplement</a></li>
                <li><a href='Probiotics.html'>Probiotics</a></li>
                <li><a href='.html'>Fatty Acids</a></li>
                <li><a href='Trace_Minerals.html'>Trace Minerals</a></li>
                <li><a href='Fibre_Supplement.html'>Fibre Supplement</a></li>
                <li><a href='Bowel_Supplement.html'>Bowel Supplement</a></li>
                <li><a href='Liver.html'>Liver</a></li>
                <li><a href='Adrenal_Support.html'>Adrenal Support</a></li>
                <li><a href='Digestive_Enzymes.html'>Digestive Enzymes</a></li>
                <li><a href='Cleanse.html'>Cleanse</a></li>
                <li><a href='Immune_Supplement.html'>Immune Supplement</a></li>
                <li><a href='Yeast.html'>Yeast</a></li>
                <li><a href='Stressed.html'>Stressed</a></li>
                <li><a href='Joints.html'>Joints</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback function of `.load()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav").load("nav.html", function () {
        $("#accordionNav").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            active: 1
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: isn't that the default setting?

Comment: @php_purest Which default setting are you talking about, accordion plugin ones? Because no, it is not. If you talk about `load()` ajax method, then i don't understand your comment?!

Comment: @php_purest Sorry, i'm quite confused but what is the point of this link related to this question/answer?Could you explain it?

Comment: lets say your main content is loaded by an ajax call, but the function was loaded when al your initial content was loaded, now you need to run it when your accordion content loads.  how would I get the load to trigger the accordion script?

Comment: @php_purest That's the purpose of ajax `load()` method  complete callback, just as shown in this answer. Here is the DOC:  http://api.jquery.com/load/  But still, what is the purpose of your link: http://webfarm.io/scripts/link_swapper.js ???  In fact, the more i read your comments, the less i understand what you mean, i'm afraid

Comment: it loads the html through the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

you should call accordion function once done with .load() because currently both are called asynchronously and while calling .accordion() function,html may not exist on the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#nav").load("nav.html", function () {
        jQuery("#accordionNav").accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            collapsible: true,
            active: 1
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: isn't that the default setting for when you do something like run natural page load?